# Android GraphView with String

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I want to make series like: `Double,String` but I can only use `Double.Double`.I tried use static labels with `setHorizontalLabels` but then I don't know how to add custom point to graph. Help please.

**EDIT**

```
    graphView = (GraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.graph_view);

    StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graphView);
    staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"old", "middle", "new"});
    graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
```

And now I want to have only three points, for example: P1("old",2), P2("middle",5), P3("new",10).
How can I handle it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please give more details, show what did you try and what exactly you need.

Comment: I would make BarGraph, on X axis I want to have Strings and on Y axis number.

Comment: `DataPoint` is only for Doubles

Comment: Where do you want to set it? Can you show some code. I need more context to Help you.

Comment: Main question was changed